# How to get all words from csv file on my x axis in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

Code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

ax=df.plot(kind='line', y='Count',logx=True,logy=True)

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(df.index)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(df['Words'])
plt.figure(figsize=(100,100))

plt.show()
```

CSV FILE:

```
Words,Count
ca,110
tc,103
cg,103
gt,100
cc,98
at,96
gc,95
ct,95
aa,94
ta,94
ac,94
tt,91
ag,87
gg,84
ga,79
tg,77
```

Result:

[image: Click here]

Is it possible to show clearly everything on my x axis? I've tried change figsize but it doesn't help. How to show all of this words on my x axis. When I comment these lines :

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(df.index) and plt.figure(figsize=(100,100))
```

My plot looks like:

[image: Click here]

How to get all of this words on my x axis?

Comment: Pass `x` to `plot`: `ax=df.plot(x='Words', y='Count',logx=True,logy=True)`

Comment: My plot still looks the same only what change i've got my x axis signed

Comment: Why would you set the x-axis to log for categorical? Remove `logx=True` and set `kind='bar'`, because the line plot, in this case, is nearly meaningless.

Comment: yes i know that but i need this in kind='line' and i need double logarithm scale